# Is it allowed to include Youtube Video in iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, video, youtube

I want to include some youtube videos in my app, is it allowed to add youtube videos by apple? I am not sure if apple will reject the app or not, if i add any youtube video.

I know that for images, we can't add any image or else your app will be rejected by Apple. So for image i use googled images which are free to use. Is there any restriction for youtube videos as well?

Thanks,
Richa

Comment: As long as the video returned by your model its fine. eg: A user in facebook might post or reshare apple's video from youtube. 
But if you are hard coding a video from apple. Apple will reject your app for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes we can allow the YouTube Video into iOS app.

> Because YouTube-provides native iOS video player to play the content
>   that you retrieve. You can access the documentation for the various
>   API endpoints offered, including ones not covered in this article, at
>   https://developers.google.com/youtube/.

[Integrating YouTube](http://www.codemag.com/article/1601081)

Answer (score 3):

**My App got reject from Apple Review stating this  (AUG/2020)**

[Guideline 5.2.3 - Legal](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#intellectual-property)

I'm using the ***youtube data api v3*** to get the popular videos by country and  display as a list on the app (App built using Flutter). each list item displaying only the title, description, thumbnail image and upload date. when click on list item to stream the video I launched in youtube app. (no steaming in my app). but apple reject my app stating above.

check this on apple [developer forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/111383)

Comment: Hello Sam! Any solution?